# CURL using getRuntime.exec() in JAVA

Tags: java, curl, runtime, exec

When i hit the curl in my cmd, its working. It returns a json response. But the output comes as blank for the below code.

```
    String output = "";
            String command = "curl -k -u snehasis:<API KEY> http://example.com";
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                p.waitFor(); 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) 
                {
                output.concat(line + "\n"); 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    return output;
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Help please?

Comment: Do you have to use curl? Anything too tricky for HttpUrlConnection or Apache HttpClient (or another Java solution) to handle?

Comment: If the output is long, `waitFor` will deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
output.concat(line + "\n");
```

You get back the concatenated String, but you don't change the value of `output`.

Java strings are **immutable**. The don't change by themselves. You need to change them.

Use:

```
output = output.concat(line + "\n");
```

Comment: Even better to use a StringBuilder. And why read line-by-line in the first place?

Comment: @Thilo Oh yes. And, The strings of StringBuilder are also mutable!